# Changing dropdown tabs with array choices

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have multiple dropdown tabs which I want to populate by using arrays,  and I want certain dropdown tabs to cause a change to what other drop down tabs would show. So i set up the arrays using if statements. But It does not seem to be working, and im not sure if its because they way I have it done just, well basically cannot be programmed that way, or if ive made a stupid mistake somewhere.

This is the code I have

```
var ticketAmount_ = document.getElementById("ticketAmount");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
var opt = options [i];
var element = document.createElement("option");
element.textContent = opt;
element.value = opt;
ticketAmount_.appendChild(element);
;
}
var movieName = function() {
document.getElementById('movieName').options.length = 0;
if (document.getElementById("ticketAmount").value == 1) {
var movieSelection1 = document.getElementById("movieName");
var options = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options [i];
    var element = document.createElement("option");
    element.textContent = opt;
    element.value = opt;
    movieSelection1.appendChild(element);

}
}
else if
 (document.getElementById("ticketAmount").value == 2) {
var movieSelection2 = document.getElementById("movieName");
var options = ["E", "F", "G", "H"];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options [i];
    var element = document.createElement("option");
    element.textContent = opt;
    element.value = opt;
    movieSelection2.appendChild(element);
    ;
}
}
};
```

And I have the movieName function set to start on the window.onload.

Is this actually possible to do?

I am new to javascript so sorry if this is not a classified as a great question, for some reason my simple questions are getting voted down, but hey we all need to learn somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want this to run on load?  and not in response to a change in the first select?

I think you're after something like this:

```
<div>
  <select id='ticketAmount' onchange="movieName()"></select>
  <select id='movieName'></select>
</div>
```

and then for your js:

```
var ticketAmount_ = document.getElementById("ticketAmount");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options [i];
    var element = document.createElement("option");
    element.textContent = opt;
    element.value = opt;
    ticketAmount_.appendChild(element);
    ;
}
var movieName = function() {
document.getElementById('movieName').options.length = 0;
if (document.getElementById("ticketAmount").value == 1) {
    var movieSelection1 = document.getElementById("movieName");
    var options = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options [i];
        var element = document.createElement("option");
        element.textContent = opt;
        element.value = opt;
        movieSelection1.appendChild(element);

    }
}
else if
(document.getElementById("ticketAmount").value == 2) {
    var movieSelection2 = document.getElementById("movieName");
    var options = ["E", "F", "G", "H"];

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options [i];
        var element = document.createElement("option");
        element.textContent = opt;
        element.value = opt;
        movieSelection2.appendChild(element);
        ;
    }
}
};
```

Note that I've cleared the options in the second select with 'options.length = 0' before adding them.

You've mentioned you're new to js, so I thought I'd mention a couple of other concepts you could look up to save yourself effort/code:

- Use a Switch statement instead of if/else
- Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY).  Whether using an if/else of switch, you should be able to:

  1. Clear the options
  2. inside your switch determine an array of appropriate options
  3. outside/after the switch (or if/else) add the elements to the select (the 'for' loop that you have repeated for both options)

Comment: I guess either, either run on load or on selection. I wasnt sure how to really set it up so thats why i set it up, with onload. 

1 issue I am having though is getting the drop downbox to display next to the name of the what the drop down box is called.
I have changed your code slightly to 

    <td>Ticket Amount :</td> <td><select id='ticketAmount' 
    onchange="movieName()"></select> <td> Film Name :</td>
            <select id='movieName'></select>

But I can only get the dropbox to show next to ticket amount and not Film name, if you could shed some light it would be appreciated

Comment: Great! if that helped you, please accept the answer.  The problem with your last select is that its not inside a <td> I think.  Check out this codePen: https://codepen.io/morganisbatman/pen/xPqypx